# Deactivate or take control of Intel Vpro and Me

Tags: motherboard, wake-on-lan, vpro, intel-amt

Processor is i5 4590 (Vpro capable)

Chipset is B85 (Vpro not capable - http://ark.intel.com/products/75019 ).
Motherboard is MSI B85 gaming - http://us.msi.com/support/mb/B85M_GAMING.html

After installing several tools from intel, I finally found out that Vpro of i5 is up on that "not supported" chipset! Please correct me if I am wrong. But the chipset information in intel site says that B85 it is not Vpro supported. If Vpro is not up, how Intel Anti Theft is running?

What this means to me as a desktop user at home who has no interest of remote management of THAT KIND and not subject to be managed by anyone else using those remote wake up on s0,s1,s2,s3... sleeping mode?

As the motherboard does NOT support Vpro, is it free from the risk of any kind of out-of-band remote connection including remote provisioning? Or is it still under the risk just because the processor has it?

If yes, how can I have the control or preferably disable that in all possible ways?

If no, then why there is Intel ME version listed in the Uefi [BIOS]? How can "Intel management and Security Status" can show the below listed information including AT service? How can I disable any sort of remote connection attempt by or attempted to my pc which uses Vpro or ME or AT or AMT? The target is to element all sorts of provisioning or pre-os communication.

**Additional information**

UEFI [Bios shows no option to enter Intel Vpro MEBx or ME. Only ME version number is available]

On windows 7 "Intel management and Security Status" gives information like

Item    Value
ME Control Mode Not Provisioned 
**Provisioning Mode Pre Provisioning**
BIOS boot   NA
Last ME reset reason    Power Up
Local FWUpdate  NA
**Power Policy  Desktop: ON in S0, ME Wake in S3, S4-5**
Cryptography Support    NA

[FW Capabilities]

Item    Value
Intel(R) Small Business Technology  Enabled 
**Intel(R) Anti-Theft Technology PC Protection  Enabled**
**Intel(R) Capability Licensing Service Enabled**
**Intel(R) Dynamic Application Loader   Enabled**
**Protect Audio Video Path  Enabled**

[Intel(R) Small Business Technology]

Item    Value
**Intel(R) SBT State    Enabled**
Intel(R) SBT Status Not Configured

[Intel(R) Anti-Theft Technology PC Protection]

Item    Value
**Intel(R) AT State Enabled**
Intel(R) AT Status  NA

Item    Value
MEBx Version    NA
FW Version  9.0.30.1482 
LMS Version 9.0.0.1323
MEI Driver Version  9.0.0.1287
SOL Driver Version  NA
SOL DeviceID    NA

[Network information]

Item    Value
LAN MAC Address NA
LAN Configuration state NA
LAN Link Status NA
LAN IPv4 Address    NA
LAN IPv6 Enablement NA
WLAN MAC Address    NA
WLAN Configuration state    NA
WLAN Link Status    NA
WLAN IPv4 Address   NA
WLAN IPv6 Enablement    NA

I will very much appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Intel B85 support Intel SBA - it is a castrated version of AMT "for Small Business". It can do some "remote things". If you afraid of that you can disabled SBA in BIOS or at all disable Intel ME - Intel AMT is a part (a module) of Intel ME.